# Polymorphism refering to childclass

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have an assignment, where I should make a mazegame. In that game I have to include polymorphism.

I want to run the method in my childclass Snake, but when I try to access it from my Game class **it runs the method in the parentclass Monsters instead of the one in the childclass Snake**

Since my whole code is really confusing, I will only post the code necessary, if needed for the context I can post more.

My parentclass:

```
package tag1;
import textio.SysTextIO;
import textio.TextIO;

public class Monsters {

    TextIO io = new TextIO(new SysTextIO());

    public void fight(){
        io.put("You have encountered a Monster, will you fight it for a 
potential reward?");   
    }

}
```

My childclass - **The method in this class is the one i want to run**

```
package tag1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Snake extends Monsters {

public void fight(Player p, ArrayList<String>currentInventory) {


    boolean condition = true;
    String choice;
    io.put("You have encountered a resting SNAKE, will you fight it for a 
potential reward? Y/N \n");
    choice = io.get();
    while (condition) {
        switch (choice) {
            case "y":
                io.put("The snake seems to realize your intentions, it looks like it is going to bite, \n"
                        + " will you punch it or stomp on it? type P/S \n");
                choice = io.get();
                if (choice.equals("P")) {
                    io.put("You got too close, and the snake bit you! , and you lost 20 health!\n");
                    p.setHealth(p.getHealth()-20);
                    io.put("you Currently have " + p.getHealth());
                    //Alternativt kan man give personen et vigtigt ITEM senere i spillet, med et andet
                    //dyr fra Monster superklasssen
                } else if(choice.equals("S")){
                    io.put("You succesfully killed the snake, with your stomp, and discover"
                            + "a healthpotion underneath the snake!\n");
                    currentInventory.add("healtpotion");
                    io.put("Healthpotion added to inventory - to use healthpotion type HP");
                }   condition = false;
                break;
            case "n":
                io.put("you silently move around, as the snake rests \n");
                condition = false;
                break;
            default:
                io.put("Seems like you have entered something invalid, type Y / N \n");
                choice = io.get();
                break;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

In my game Class i have this method

```
public void monsterFight(Player p, ArrayList<Room> roomList){
    if (p.getCurrentRoom().equals(roomList.get(1))) {
       fightMonsters(snakeObject);
    }
}
```

-->

```
public void fightMonsters(Monsters variabel){
    variabel.fight();
}
```

**But this goes method refers to my parentclass version of fight() instead of the childclass version?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Methods signature

You're not calling the proper method: At the end, your `Snake` class has two fight method signatures:

- `public void fight()` (from `Monster` class)
- `public void fight(Player p, ArrayList<String>currentInventory)` (from `Snake` class)

which means that in your `monsterFight(Player p, ArrayList<Room> roomList)` method, you have to change to something like:

```
public void monsterFight(Player p, ArrayList<Room> roomList){
    if (p.getCurrentRoom().equals(roomList.get(1))) {
       // your monster has to fight a player!
       fightMonsters(snakeObject, p);

       // option B is to directly call:
       // snakeObject.fight(p, p.getInventory());
       // with the assumption on getInventory() defined later
    }
}
```

with also the following changes:

```
public void fightMonsters(Monsters variabel, Player p){
    variabel.fight(p, p.getInventory());
}
```

assuming that `getInventory();` signature is `public List<String> getInventory();`. This way, your monster is calling the proper method.

### Abstract class

**However**, this is still incorrect: in `Monster` class, `fight(Player, List<String>)` does not exist. One option is to declare your Monster as an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Monster{
    public void fight(){
        // your method that you define
    }

    // this method has to be overridden in children classes
    public abstract void fight(Player p, List<String> inventory);
}
```

Consequently, your Snake class will look like:

```
public class Snake extends Monster{

    @Override
    public void fight(Player p, List<String> inventory){
        // your method
    }

}
```

Then, you can call a `fight` method for any monster.

Comment: You're welcomed! Thanks for accepting my answer! Please consider upvoting the other answers if you consider them as useful. PS: abstract classes for the win !

Answer (score 3):

Method overloading works only if the overloaded and overloading methods have the same signature, meaning the same parameter types and same return type.

The method in `Snake` has two arguments, while the method in `Monsters` has no parameters at all, so it is not overloaded.

When you call `Snake.fight()`, such a method is searched for but not found (no method is called `fight()` and accepts zero arguments), so the parent method is called.

Bonus:
The `Monsters` class looks like a simple parent class for all the monster types such as snake, skeleton, goblin or whatever, which should never be instantiated. In such case it's probably better to make it `abstract`, with no method implementations at all, so you won't invoke it's methods by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism in Java is the ability of an object to have different forms, for example for a class to call different methods.

The compiler can choose between the two `fight` methods because they are different, based upon the number (and types) of arguments passed.

`Snake.fight(Player, ArrayList<String>)` has 2 parameters, and `Monster.fight()` has 0 parameter.